# Notificações em Tempo Real com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

Estou construindo uma aplicação em Java que deverá mostrar na tela notificações em tempo real.

1. Um professor solicita uma reserva;
2. Os dados da reserva são armazenados num objeto json (ou numa tabela de solicitações);
3. Na mesma hora, uma notificação é exibida na tela do operador;
4. O operador pode aprovar a reserva, o que daria um `INSERT` no banco com os dados da reserva.

Imaginei que a forma com json seria mais fácil, assim não envolveria Java nem SQL no processo. Mas minha dúvida: é como fazer isso exatamente? Não sei muita coisa sobre JavaScript ainda, mas imagino que seria necessário o uso de ajax, correto? Poderiam me ajudar nessa?

Comment: `java` ou `javascript` ?

Comment: Como sua pergunta é muito ampla, e Real Time pode variar muito de complexidade, vou sugerir que tu comece tua pesquisa com Node.js:  https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: @Douglas, a aplicação em si é escrita em Java, mas o que eu quero fazer não precisa necessariamente de Java, por isso foquei no JavaScript e no jQuery.

Comment: @ThiagoSantos, obrigado. Vou dar uma investida em node.js.

Comment: Acredito que, como não acrescentaremos nada a comunidade aqui, seja melhor fechar essa pergunta. Uma última dica: https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/using-nodejs-create-real-time-web-applications é um bom ponto de partida!

Comment: Veja se ajuda: http://gabrielfeitosa.com/angularjs-refresh-periodico/

Answer (score 3):

Tem duas opções principalmente.

Uma é fazer o chamado polling via ajax, ou seja, no client do operador é enviada uma requisição a cada x intervalo de tempo para verificar se existe uma nova reserva. Essa é uma forma simples de verificar as informações mas são enviadas muita requisições ao servidor desnecessárias.
Veja um exemplo que faz uma chamada a cada 5 segundos:

```
(function poll() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/server/api/function",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("polling");
        },
        dataType: "json",
        complete: poll,
        timeout: 2000
    })
}, 5000);
```

})();

A outra solução é usar os websockets através da API [Socket.io](http://socket.io) para manter uma conexão aberta entre o client e o servidor sem precisar fazer queries inúteis. Esse é um artigo antigo mas pode ajudar [Conectando no Socket.io](http://imasters.com.br/tecnologia/redes-e-servidores/conectando-no-socket-io-o-basico/)

Mesmo que você não conheça muito de javascript vale a pena explorar a segunda opção que é mais atual e avançada.

Comment: Obrigado, riotera e Thiago Santos, vou dar uma olhada nos links que vcs enviaram. Vou dar uma aprofundada no Socket.io, que ambos os links falam.